# How can I draw with D3Js chart with my array of objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, d3.js

Im trying to create flowchart with my custom json format. each object will create a flow with data inside.

I achived to create first, but cannot loop through other array of json data.

My json data:

```
var processMain = {
            "process": [{
                "ProcessName" : "Record One", 
                "Username" : "Joh Doe", 
                "Created" : "10:00:00",
                'records': [
                  "Titles goes here",
                  "This is another title"
                ],
                'display': [
                  {
                    'question': "Question one",
                    'answer': "answer goes here"
                  },
                  {
                    'question': "Question Two",
                    'answer': "answer goes here"
                  }
                ]
            }],
            "chapterOne": [{
                "ProcessName" : "Second Record", 
                "Username" : "Joh Hoe", 
                "Created" : "10:00:00",
                'records': [
                  "Titles goes here",
                  "This is another title"
                ],
                'display': [
                  {
                    'question': "Question one",
                    'answer': "answer goes here"
                  },
                  {
                    'question': "Question Two",
                    'answer': "answer goes here"
                  }
                ]
            }]
        };
```

My fiddle shows the working sample so far done.
https://jsfiddle.net/vickyparab76/y0duk4je/3/

Appreciated your help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [D3js get the array of keys to draw chart from json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54264880/d3js-get-the-array-of-keys-to-draw-chart-from-json)